# Why was I given 100 points for asking my first question on Webapps Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

As directed by a user in response to a comment on my question, I asked the question on Webapps also on Stack exchange (for the first time as I never knew there are other sites like this) and immediately I got 100 points (not that I'm complaining). Can someone please explain to me as to why this is so?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because you [linked to your Ask Ubuntu account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/14855/mysterio?tab=accounts), which has over 200 reputation. You get 100 rep on every other Stack Exchange account so long as one of you linked accounts has more than 200 reputation.

Answer (score 10):

If you have 200+ rep on one Stack Exchange site, then when you join another you are given 100 when you join another. This is in recognition of the fact you know how the SE model works, so you can get stuck in (and not have to wait for privileges such as commenting).